# How to use std::num_put with a custom iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

How do I use [`std::num_put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put) to write a number to a custom iterator (for example a `std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>`)?

```
std::string s;
using I = decltype(std::back_inserter(s));
auto& f = std::use_facet<std::num_put<char, I>>(std::locale());
f.put(std::back_inserter(s), /* what do I pass here? */, ' ', 5.6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be using `std::num_put` directly, with a `std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>`. Your code there is not modifying the `locale`'s behaviour, so I don't know what you are trying to do with the facet.

Instead, consider imbuing a `std::stringstream` with whatever facets you want, and then performing normal stream insertions.

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::locale loc = // Some non-standard locale ?
ss.imbue(loc); // if you have changed anything
ss << 5.6;
std::string s = ss.str();
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to use a custom iterator that is not backed by a string, the `back_insert_iterator` is only there to simplify the question.

Comment: What's the point of the iterator type in the template if the only iterator you're supposed to use is `ostreambuf_iterator`?

Comment: @eyelash any iterator adapters wrapping `std::ostreambuf_iterator`, for a start. You *could* use any `std::ios_base` unrelated to your iterator